# Support for Modern Events Calendar lite - hide registration (or zoom links) from users not logged in

Tags: wordpress, events, calendar, memberpress

I am looking to hide the registration links from users that are not members (or if not possible then from those users not logged in). Even with the page protected by memberpress (https://memberpress.com/)the right sidebar with the register link and information displays. IS there a way to just hide the "Register button" - or event link from users that are not members (or alternatively not logged in) through this software (https://webnus.net/modern-events-calendar/). I can hide page content or parts of page content using shortcodes but have not been able to hide the defauly button unless I don't enter any info and then add it to the page. Thank you.  Page is: https://iirrma.org/events/december-2023-case-discussion/. And screenshot attached.

I have tried using different page protections through Memberpress and User Access.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.